# Which version of EJB is supported on JBoss EAP 6.3?

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x, jboss-eap-6

Can anybody please tell me, which version of EJB is supported on JBoss EAP 6.3 ?

My current application is running on JBoss AS 4.0.3 and EJB 1.1 . I want to upgrade it to JBoss EAP 6.3. Does EJB 1.1 is supported on JBoss EAP 6.3?

Answer (score 2):

[*Not suitable for comment, little lengthier. These are only pointers, may not directly answer the question, but indirectly can help*]

- Try to go through JBoss documentation first for the specific version, which you are intended to use.
- Look into the changes made in the version, there is reasonable amount of documentation provided about the features supported/added in that particular release.
- Go to specific version [download](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap/download/) page.
- [Frequently asked questions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/6.3.0_Release_Notes/Frequently_Asked_Questions4.html)
- Refer [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/113373) [JBoss Enterprise Application Platform Supported Standards] for the release version you are looking to utilize.
- There you can find details; Enterprise JavaBeans with Interceptors 1.1 (EJB) [JSR-153, 220, 318] **3.1, 3.0, 2.1, 2.0** for JBoss EAP 6.

Comment: Actually - that's a better answer, I think, than just saying which version is supported. Teach A Man To Fish...and all that.

Answer (score 0):

For the record

Meh, to many turns to say:

Support JDK 6, 7 and 8 (8 only for EAP 6.3.3 and higher)

Answer (score 0):

Or, to be specific - No, JBoss EAP 6.3 does not support the EJB 1.1 specification.